# Jython can not use lxml library

Tags: java, python, lxml, jython

I'm trying to use zeep library to provide soap call in python code and its okay it works when I try to run with python. Then, I'm trying to use jython to run this code (i need jython because next step will be on the server that uses jython to compile)  and when I try to install lxml for jython it gives me this error:

**error:Compiling extensions is not supported on Jython**

When I search for this situation, I found that jython doesn't support c based libraries.

So, there is a solution with jython-jni bridge but I couldn't understand how to be.
Is there another solution? Or can you give me an obvious example?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't achieve to implement jni but i created a new layer between jython and server.I mean, i made a REST call from jython compiler and this call listens my server for soap call and it worked.